# RabbitMQ Service starts and then stopped due to RabbitMQ: Erlang machine seems to die continously, not restarted

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I installed `Erlang` (OTP 21.2 Windows 64-bit Binary File) followed by `RabbitMQ Server 3.7.9` and I also installed management tool `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`.

Now whenever I try to start `RabbitMQ` service, after 1 minutes, it's stopped.

Below event I'm getting,

> Info > RabbitMQ: Erlang service restarted
>
> Error >RabbitMQ: Erlang machine seems to die continously, not
>   restarted.
>
> The RabbitMQ service terminated with the following error: 
>   The process terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: I found that I have windows service bus 1.1 also running and both service bus and rabbitmq not able to co-exist. Once uninstall service bus, rabbitmq works for me. Thanks!

Comment: There is also this similar question, but no conclusive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32995708/371917